# How to find out if QTextCodec is compatible with ASCII?

Tags: c++, qt, codepages

I want to create a list of all Qt Text codes which are compatible with ASCII. Maybe I use the wrong term here, but I mean those where the values < 128 (first seven bits) represent valid ASCII characters. Example: UTF8 is Ok, UTF16 is not.

I wonder if the `MIBenum` tells me that? Ref: https://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xhtml

So from `QtextCodec::availableCodecs()`I want to exclude those which do NOT meet the criteria (ASCII-compatible). Any idea how to best do this?

Comment: Normally, writers tell readers which character encoding to use before or while passing the bytes (such as by spec or standard, or HTTP response header Content-Type). What's your goal here? Some sort of internal declaration like XML's encoding or HTML's meta charset?

Comment: We have an application where the user can select the codec (i.e. the `QTextCodec`). But the codec must be ASCII compatible, I want to create that selection list from `QtextCodec::availableCodecs()` and exclude those not meeting the requirement (e.g. UTF-16).